# date format in dd.mm.yyyy in mongodb using nodejs driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

can anyone help me how can i save documents in mongodb using nodejs driver with 
a field createdDate in the date format dd.mm.yyyy

I have tried to do so but in schema on type:date is getting accepted
and when type:string i am still unable to save the date

```
  let today = new Date();
  let day = today.getDate();
  let month = today.getMonth() + 1;
  let year = today.getFullYear();
  let hour = today.getHours();
  let minutes = today.getMinutes();
  let seconds = today.getSeconds();
  crdate =`${day}.${month}.${year}.${hour}.${minutes}.${seconds}`

  const order = new VendorOrder({
    ...req.body,
    vendorOrders: req._id,
    crdate
    });
 try {
    await order.save();
    res.status(201).send(order);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: "unable to create order"
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried ? Also read [ask] questions and [mre] on StackOverflow.

Comment: As far as I know you can't store a date field in this format `dd.mm.yyyy` in mongoDB, you can store it in string format !! Why do you need it that way ? You can convert `ISODate()` to that format just in case if you needed that on read queries..

Comment: i have edited my questn,please check the code it tried to save that in the needed format though i didnot work,i need it bcoz csv file has the date in that format and i have been asked to save dates in the same format,as a string i can but i am able to save it when i get that date from req.body, is it possible when i send a post request i can save the document in that format